# How can we encode the image into the body of the email when sending mail using database mail in sql 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-mail

How can we encode the image into the body of the email when sending mail using database mail in sql 2008
I m using :

```
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'DBMail',
    @recipients = 'goldenash21@gmail.com',
    @subject = 'DB hello',
    --@file_attachments = 'C:\logo.jpg',    
    @body='<p>Image Test</p><img src="C:\logo.jpg" width="270" height="146"" /><p>See image there?</p>' , 
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Any help would be highly appreciable..
Thanks

Comment: If your HTML says that the image source is `c:\logo.jpg` then the email reader needs to be able to see that file at `c:\logo.jpg`, *on their computer*.  Try hosting the image online and using a URL that references the online file?

Comment: Thanks .. Passing online reference of image  works ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You've almost done it:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'DBMail',
@recipients = 'goldenash21@gmail.com',
@subject = 'DB hello',
@file_attachments = 'C:\logo.jpg;C:\logo2.jpg;',    
@body='<p>Image Test</p><img src="logo.jpg" width="270" height="146"" /><p>See image there?</p><img src="logo2.jpg" width="270" height="146"" />' , 
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

Attach required images using `@file_attachments` separate them using `;` an then use their names (only file name with extension) in `@body`.